# Permission denied when attempt to create/remove/rename files in write-only directory

Tags: linux, file-permissions, permission-denied

There are tons of posts on the net saying that write permission on directory allows affected user to `create/remove/rename` files in that directory, but I found that it actually could not be done without execute permission set. I tried calling `open/fopen/remove/rename`, but without exception, they all failed.

There should be something I missed or something I misunderstood. There are some explanation that operations on directory usually involves with file operation. If it was right, I wonder what operation is involved. If directory maintains mappings from filename to inode, it seems no reason that file operation is involved when renaming.

If unexpected file operation is involved, is it possible to manipulate directory directly, bypassing such operations?

Answer (score 0):

You are right, the net is full of wrong things and especially for unix file permission rules. The first links I found with a common search engine were all wrong. Very interesting!

What file permissions on directories means:

x you have "access" to the files in this directory which means you can use them. If you do not have read access but access rights, you can work with a file which you know but you can't see!

```
mkdir one
touch one/x.h
chmod -r one

ls one   // fails!
cat one/x.h  // works!
```

and write permission is used for changing the content of the directory. So adding and removing files from the dir is only possible if you have write permission on that dir!

Because it is impossible to read/write/execute a file which is inside a dir which you can't access, you always need access rights for the dir to work with the files inside.

Sounds a bit strange, but is simply implemented that way.